# FileOutputStream: Stream closed

Tags: java, file, io

**Solved, In short: the problem was that I wrote to an already closed FileOutputStream**

I noticed some strange semantics using the FileOutputStream class.

If I create a FileOutputStream using this code:

```
try {
    File astDumpFile = new File(dumpASTPath);
    if(!astDumpFile.exists()) {
        astDumpFile.createNewFile();
    }
    astDumpStream = new FileOutputStream(dumpASTPath);
} catch( IOException e ) {
    dumpAST = false;
    //throw new IOException("Failed to open file for dumping AST: " + dumpASTPath);
    System.out.println("Failed to open file for dumping AST: " + dumpASTPath);
}
```

at the beginning of the program (`astDumpStream` is a member variable). Then if I later (~3 seconds later) write string data to the file, i get an `IOException: stream closed`:

```
try {
    String dotGraph = gpvisitor.getDotGraph();
    astDumpStream.write(dotGraph.getBytes("UTF8"));
    astDumpStream.flush();
    astDumpStream.close();
} catch( IOException e ) {
    System.out.println("Failed to dump AST to file: " + e.getMessage());
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

However if I copy the excact code which I use to create the `FileOutputStream` to directly before writing to it, it works as expected.

Now I wonder why do I get that exception if I create that object earlier, but not if I create it directly before I use it.

EDIT: The exception:

```
java.io.IOException: Stream Closed
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.writeBytes(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.write(FileOutputStream.java:305)
    at MyClass.function(MyClass.java:208)
```

I just noticed, that even though I get an exception, still some data was written to the file. Interrestingly the first line is written completely, then all following lines except the last line are missing.
If I replace the written String `dotGraph` with something shorter everything is written correctly, however I still get that exception.

EDIT: Environment Information:

```
[~]> lsb_release -a
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux testing (wheezy)
Release:        testing
Codename:       wheezy
[~]> java -version
java version "1.7.0_09"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_09-b05)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.5-b02, mixed mode)
```

Comment: You haven't really given us enough code to figure out where the stream is being closed. My best guess is that you call that second block of code more than once (so it closes it the first time and throws an exception the second).

Comment: Also creating the file is superfluous. FileOutputStream tries to create the file and only throws FileNotFoundException if it can't: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html#FileOutputStream%28java.io.File%29

Comment: @Brendan Long: Thats the only code accessing that FileOutputStream object.

Comment: If you only access it in that one place, then why is it a member variable and not local? Just open it right before you write to it..

Comment: @Brendan Long: I am aware of that, but I want to understand why this issue occurs, so i am not cueless when something like this happens again.

Comment: Like I said, I think this is occurring because you execute that second block of code more than once.

Comment: @BrendanLong: You were right, i set a breakpoint, and indeed it was executed twice, go ahead and write an answer (my identation was broken, so i did not see that the piece of code was inside a loop :/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way this can happen if is the `close()` function gets called more than once. My guess is that for some reason, the second block of code is being called more than once.

To prevent indentation errors, there are two good pieces of advice I've received:

- Always indent consistently. Preferably use a tool that does this for you (like Eclipse).
- Always use curly braces, even if you don't think you need them. This helps prevent quite a few minor bugs that take forever to find, so the extra half-second it takes to type each one is more than made up by the hours you don't spend looking for these bugs.

Answer (score 4):

The only reason to get an `IOException` complaining that the stream is closed is because the stream was closed. You'll have to trace through your code to find out where that's happening. Some not-so-obvious places include calls into other methods and `finally` blocks of `try` statements. Another thing to look for is reassignment of the variable `astDumpStream` to a different stream (that was closed before the `IOException` was raised—possibly even before the first assignment to `astDumpStream`).

The time doesn't seem relevant unless you have a separate thread that might close the stream after a delay.

Comment: i dont use or access `astDumpStream` outside the code snippets i posted and `astDumpStream` is the only reference to that stream object.

Comment: @smerlin - I'm wondering if something is going on at the OS level. Is the file located somewhere weird (like a network drive) where there could be some sort of time-out on the underlying native stream?

Comment: Since i was testing this on a computer at my university, and since the home directories of those machines are network shares, i tested this again in a local directory of that computer (`/tmp`). However the issue still occured.

Answer (score 0):

To Second Tedd - in case you happen to use a nested try with resource block and using stream outside tryblock - you could run in this situation as well because once the control comes out of nested try with resource block the stream will be closed.

Comment: Another way this can happen.  You have multiple tasks reading or writing and they are using the same File instance.  If one of the threads changes the file instance, that'll cause a changed file instance to be closed.  In multithreading code, its not necessarily easy to notice that you inadvertently close a file that is being used by a different thread.  That happened to me, I had the file defined as a class attribute instead of at the method scope level.